# How to make table responsive

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I have some table and I want to make it responsive when it show in width max 760.

This is the table looks normal :

[image]

And I want to make it like this if width of the screen is max 760 :

[image]

In that table the last coloumn just appears in end of table not in each row.

Anyone can help me to do that ?

Comment: Hi, Instead of table use ul li. Because it is not supported in all browser.

Comment: could you use bootstrap. this framework  will help you to create a responsive page.

Comment: you can try this http://sitesforprofit.com/responsive-tables-in-wordpress

Comment: Yes I already did some research with bootstrap but it just give me table with scroll horizontal and cannot looks like what I want. @esprittn

Comment: take a look at this URL. this may help you : https://elvery.net/demo/responsive-tables/

Comment: @Sasith Okay I will try this. But I want to make the last coloumn just show in end of the table that's make me confuse.

Comment: You can add a class to that td and hide it in mobile. Then add div with a link to book-now after table to show in mobile.

Comment: you can achieve those position by setting your `td` to `display:block`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this html & css code  for  make rsponsive  table**

Check the Snippets is below .

- Use this css with media query **max-width:760px or any width**

```css
.responsive-table {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:500px;
 border: 1px solid #efebeb;
  
  }
  
  .responsive-table img{height:100px; }
  
  .responsive-table th {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .responsive-table td {
    display: block;
 border-top: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  .responsive-table td:first-child{border:none;}
  .responsive-table td:first-child {
    padding-top: .5em;
  }
  .responsive-table td:last-child {
    padding-bottom: .5em;
  }
  .responsive-table td:before {
    content: attr(data-th) ": ";
    display:block;
 font-weight:bold;
  }
```

```html
<table class="responsive-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Room
            </th>
            <th>
                Guest
            </th>
            <th>
                Description
            </th>
            <th>
                Rate
            </th>
            <th>
                Book
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td data-th="Room">
                <img src="http://i45.tinypic.com/t9ffkm.jpg" alt="" />
            </td>
            <td data-th="Guest">
                2 adult
            </td>
            <td data-th="Description">
                Room Only

            </td>
            <td data-th="Rate">
                USD 200

            </td>
            <td data-th="Book">
                <button type="submit"> Book</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote js function to make table responsive. You can set breakpoint and table tag or css class name as parameters.

```
    const makeTableResponsive = (mq, t) => {
    var q = window.matchMedia(mq);
    if (q.matches) {
        let headings = [];
        let tables = document.querySelectorAll(t);
        if (tables && tables.length > 0) {
            tables.forEach(table => {
                let thead = table.querySelector("thead");
                let headingTags = thead.querySelectorAll("th");
                let tbody = table.querySelector("tbody");
                let tbodies = tbody.querySelectorAll("tr");
    
                tbody.style.display = "block";
                thead.style.display = "none";
    
                headingTags.forEach((th) => {
                    th.style.display = "block";
                    headings.push(th.innerText);
                });
    
                tbodies.forEach((tr) => {
                    let trstyle = tr.style;
                    trstyle.display = "block";
                    trstyle.border = "1px solid #ccc";
                    trstyle.marginBottom = "30px";
    
                    let tds = tr.querySelectorAll("td");
                    tds.forEach((td, i) => {
                        td.style.display = "flex";
                        td.style.flexDirection = "row-reverse";
                        td.style.justifyContent = "space-between";
                        td.innerHTML += `<span class="font-weight-bold text-primary">${headings[i]}</span>`;
                    });
                });
            })
        }
    }
};


makeTableResponsive('(max-width: 992px)', 'table');
```