# How to setup responsive code for particular table class?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to set below mentioned responsive table code for particular table class file. how to do it. I am using CSSTableGenerator as a table class. if I use this code normal tables also effects. but I want to set it for CSSTableGenerator class file only. please guide me

```
/* 
    Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
    This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
    and also iPads specifically.
    */
    @media 
    only screen and (max-width: 760px),
    (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

        /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
        table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
            display: block; 
        }

        /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
        thead tr { 
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }

        tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

        td { 
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%; 
        }

        td:before { 
            /* Now like a table header */
            position: absolute;
            /* Top/left values mimic padding */
            top: 6px;
            left: 6px;
            width: 45%; 
            padding-right: 10px; 
            white-space: nowrap;
        }       

    }

    /* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen
    and (min-device-width : 320px)
    and (max-device-width : 480px) {
        body { 
            padding: 0; 
            margin: 0; 
            width: 320px; }
        }

    /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
        body { 
            //width: 495px; 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you just show part of your html?

Comment: check this link for responsive table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993076/how-to-make-table-responsive/39994278#39994278

Comment: You have add class name with table "CSSTableGenerator.table"

Answer (score 1):

/* 
    Max width before this PARTICULAR table gets nasty
    This query will take effect for any screen smaller than 760px
    and also iPads specifically.
    */
    @media 
    only screen and (max-width: 760px),
    (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

```
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table.CSSTableGenerator,.CSSTableGenerator thead,.CSSTableGenerator tbody,.CSSTableGenerator th,.CSSTableGenerator td,.CSSTableGenerator tr { 
        display: block; 
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    .CSSTableGenerator thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    .CSSTableGenerator tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    .CSSTableGenerator td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
    }

    .CSSTableGenerator td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
    }       

}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    body { 
        padding: 0; 
        margin: 0; 
        width: 320px; }
    }

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    body { 
        //width: 495px; 
    }
}
```

I hope this should help, add the exact class name which you are using for the table. In your case you are adding properties to general tag , so it will affect every table.

Comment: any one help me!!

Comment: /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    .CSSTableGenerator thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }
Remove this.

Comment: its working. but i have created another table in wordpress widget using this code    <div class="textwidget"><table style="height: 287px;" width="437">
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table></div>   but above css code change it style also. please help me

Comment: i think problem with @media 
    only screen and (max-width: 760px),
    (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) only .. change it for .CSSTableGenerator class